# How can I disable the SDL splash screen?

Tags: android, linux, sdl

I'm porting an SDL-based game from Linux to Android, and it's going very smoothly.

However, the Android version displays an SDL splash screen ("Powered by SDL") while initializing, and the Linux version doesn't.

How can I disable this SDL splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

The code for this is in MainActivity.java, around line 110. If a file "logo.png" is put in the right place, that will be displayed, otherwise it displays publisherlogo.png, which is the "Powered by SDL" file. If you comment out the line to load publisherlogo.png, the splash screen area will be black during program launch.